# HashiCorp Vault not listening on another port

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, hashicorp-vault

I have Vault deployed to AKS cluster in standalone mode via Helm chart.
My config looks like this:

```
server:
  enabled: true # enable vault server
  ha:
    enabled: false  # disable high-availability
  standalone:
    enabled: true
    config: |
      ui = true

      max_lease_ttl = "8760h"
      default_lease_ttl = "8760h"

      listener "tcp" {        
        address = "[::]:8200"        
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/iot-vautl-self-signed.crt"
        tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/iot-vautl-self-signed.key"        
      }

      # non-TLS secured endpoint for APIM connectivity
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8300"        
        tls_disable = true
      }

      cluster_address = "[::]:8201"

      storage "file" {
        path = "/vault/data"
      }
  
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: LoadBalancer
  annotations: 
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

This is the output from the logs when Vault starts up:

```
==> Vault server configuration:

             Api Address: https://172.18.0.14:8200
                     Cgo: disabled
         Cluster Address: https://vault-0.vault-internal:8201
              Go Version: go1.16.7
              Listener 1: tcp (addr: "[::]:8200", cluster address: "[::]:8201", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "enabled")
              Listener 2: tcp (addr: "[::]:8300", cluster address: "[::]:8301", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
           Recovery Mode: false
                 Storage: file
                 Version: Vault v1.8.4
             Version Sha: 925bc650ad1d997e84fbb832f302a6bfe0105bbb

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:

2021-11-10T11:00:24.448Z [INFO]  proxy environment: http_proxy="" https_proxy="" no_proxy=""
2021-11-10T11:00:25.202Z [INFO]  core: stored unseal keys supported, attempting fetch
2021-11-10T11:00:25.241Z [INFO]  core.cluster-listener.tcp: starting listener: listener_address=[::]:8201
2021-11-10T11:00:25.241Z [INFO]  core.cluster-listener.tcp: starting listener: listener_address=[::]:8301
2021-11-10T11:00:25.241Z [INFO]  core.cluster-listener: serving cluster requests: cluster_listen_address=[::]:8201
2021-11-10T11:00:25.241Z [INFO]  core.cluster-listener: serving cluster requests: cluster_listen_address=[::]:8301
```

I'm able to get to the vault thourgh the Load balancer IP address and port 8200 via HTTPS, however nothing happens when I try to use the same IP address with port 8300 via HTTP.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: The Vault Helm chart assume a single port for services, and therefore only manages a single `ClusterIP` service. If you want `HTTP` on a different port, then you would need an additional manifest for the second service. That means this is actually a Kubernetes root cause. If this is ok, then I can write up an answer.

Comment: Also, it is unclear from the question whether you mean you can connect to the Vault API or UI, and which or both of those is the desired functionality here.

Comment: For the non-tls listener API is enough

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard, will you write an answer?

Comment: Hi @jjczopek, any progress?

Comment: I want to replicate your issue. Could you please share commands used for chart installation? Which Kubernetes version are you using? Could you please run `kubectl get svc {service-name-from-hashicorp-vault} -o yaml` and check if you have proper ports assigned to your LoadBalancer?